# Differences in LINQ syntax between VB.Net and C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, c#-to-vb.net

[Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514601/reasons-to-specify-generic-types-in-linq-extension-methods), just out of curiosity:

After I have programmed several projects in VB.Net I to my surprise discovered that there are some more than subtle differences between C# and VB.NET LINQ usage.
For example, if we want to group elements by multiple properties (columns) we need to create a new anonymous type explicitly:

```
var procs = from c in Process.GetProcesses() 
            group c by new {c.BasePriority, c.Id} into d 
            select d;
```

whereas in VB.NET more straightforward syntax will already do:

```
Dim b = From c In Process.GetProcesses()
        Group c By c.BasePriority, c.Id Into Group
        Select Group
```

So, one does not need to create a type with "new" here.

What are the other differences? Is there any good comparison between the LINQ syntax in C# and VB.NET?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are some differences that I know of, mostly that VB.NET's LINQ has some hidden gems:

1. Not explicitly LINQ related, but VB.NET supports the `Key` modifier on anonymous types. This allows you to define which properties in the anonymous type are used when comparing anonymous types. As far as I can tell with C#; it uses everything. This is where VB.NET has an actual advantage.
2. VB.NET supports the `Skip` operation as a keyword:
   `Dim returnCustomers = From a In list Skip numToSkip Select a` You can do this in C#; but it has to be through the extension method, there is no syntactic sugar.
3. VB.NET LINQ also supports `Skip While`: `From a In list Skip While someCondition Select a` Again, C# can do this; but only through the extension method.
4. and 4.5.: The same as 2 & 3 except with `Take` and `Take While`
5. The `Select` keyword is optional in VB.NET. If you want to select what is current; then that works fine: `Dim shortWords = From l In list Where l.Length < 10` in C#; the Select part is required: `var shortWords = from l in list where l.Length < 10 select l`

Those are the additional "features" of VB.NET's LINQ that I am aware of.

For example; with C#:

```
var skip10 = (from c in customers select c).Skip(10);
```

And in VB.NET

```
Dim skip10 = From c In Customers Skip 10
```

You can see the documentation for all of these here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: So, if I understand you right, there are more LINQ extension methods in VB.Net can be written using operator-like syntax compared to C# (like instead of writing `(...).Skip()` one writes just `Skip` in the middle of the LINQ query. That's nice, thank you!

Comment: @Alaudo - yes, it appears that VB.NET just has more of it baked into the actual language itself. I also added #5 which indicates that the `Select` part isn't mandatory like it is in C#.

Comment: Oh, thank you for adding some more examples! 
As regards C# and LINQ, as far as I know you can skip `select` too, like `var d = from c in customers where c.Age > 18`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Alaudo: No. That will result in this compiler error: `A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause`. The error is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383932(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: There is also `Aggregate`, but that [has its own problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12264751/256431).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the answer is still true as of April 2022. Has Microsoft (or anyone else) given a rationale why C# lacks some of the convenient sytnax available in VB.NET?

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at this:

[Visual Basic vs C# LINQ syntax](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/goto100/archive/2008/08/05/visual-basic-vs-c-linq-syntax.aspx)

regards

Comment: I am primarily interested in differences as concerns LINQ, the first link is interesting but very short -- it is just a block entry. Two remaining ones are outdated comparisons of VB.Net vs. C# and do not include any information on LINQ. Pity...