# LINQ to SQL - When do I need to Select and when can I omit the Select?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I've been playing around with LINQ to SQL and I just have a couple of simple questions:

- When do I need Select on the end of my query?
- When can I omit the Select?

Here are my example queries:

```
Dim pageRoute = From r In db.PageRoutes Where r.PageId = pageId Order By r.Id Descending

Dim pageRoute = From r In db.PageRoutes Where r.PageId = pageId Order By r.Id Descending

Dim dp = From r In db.DownloadPageOnlineOnlies Where r.PageId = pageId Order By r.Weight Descending, r.Id Ascending

Dim download = (From r In db.Downloads Where r.Id = id).First
```

- Are any of them technically wrong?
- Could they be improved with a Select or something else?

In a nutshell, I don't understand when I would need either:

```
Select r
Select r.AColumnINeed, r.BColumnINeed (does this improve performance?)
```

Thanks.

P.S. I like to write my LINQ queries on one line unless they are really big.

Comment: Isn't the `Select` always optional in VB.NET? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6515130/284240

Comment: I don't know that's why I'm asking. If something is optional then I usually leave it out just to give my fingers a rest!

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515037/differences-in-linq-syntax-between-vb-net-and-c-sharp/6515130#6515130 what does it mean by "select what is current"?

Comment: If you don't specify a select, *all* is selected. `Dim q = From r In tbl.AsEnumerable
               From c In tbl.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)()` returns an anonymous type with a cartesian product of all DataRows and all DataColumns in that DataTable. Always prefer  readability, so use `Select` whenever it's unclear what the query returns.

Comment: Ok so the query would be along the lines of `Dim q = From r In tbl.AsEnumerable From c In tbl.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)() Select r.Column1, c.Column2` ?

Comment: What query? Query what you need. So if you need an anonymous type of field1 and field2(you can omit the `AsEnumerable` in VB also): `Dim q = From r In tbl
        Select New With {.Col1 = r.Field(Of String)("Column1"), .Col2 = r.Field(Of String)("Column2")}`

Comment: Ok I think I need to do some more LINQ reading at some point. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a table with 20 columns. Take a query WITH select (2 columns) and one WITHOUT. The execution plan of the two can be different and there's much less data to transfer from the database server in the former case.

Comment: Okay I understand that but, do I need to `Select r` if I want all columns e.g. `SELECT *` in T-SQL?

Comment: I am not sure about vb syntax but this should be optional and would be eliminated as an identity projection by the linq expression visitor.

Comment: So if I put Select at the end and it is not needed, it will be removed anyway? Is that during compilation or execution?

Comment: During execution, when expression visitor translates linq to sql.

Answer (score 2):

The select portion of the linq statement is completely optional if and only if you want to get a full object out of the collection that matches your `where` clause. If you want individual value(s) from an object in the collection being LINQ'd through then you need to use a select clause.

I personally always put the `select r` clause on the end just out of pure habit but I have come across a few issues with other peoples code when I have option strict on and they did not when they wrote the LINQ. Leaving the `select` clause off yields multiple late binding errors if you decide to turn `option strict on` in the future for whatever reason.

so in short you don't need the `select` clause but you are only helping yourself later on down the line if you decide to turn `option strict on`. And it does make your code much more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will consider this for my next project :)

Answer (score -1):

it a good practice to use select plus if you have a query that requests a more precise result and like you only want a or a and b from you query you might use select and it saves the memory allocation for your query since it know exact number of variables you are going to return.

Comment: But why is it best practice? I usually favour consistency and less code over best practice!

Comment: Using less code is not always means it gives the best performance

Comment: I just like to cut the fat in the code to make it easier to read, debug and maintain.

Comment: Well I'm not worried about it taking a few extra milliseconds to execute.

Comment: Other people understand the question fine.

Comment: but none of the reply make you satified